# Convert multiple json object into array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

My data is currently stored in this format:

```
{
   "Site1":{
      "week":[
         {
            "access":1
         },
         {
            "access":8
         }
      ]
   },
   "Site2":{
      "week":[
         {
            "access":16
         }
      ]
   },
   "Site3":{
      "week":[
         {
            "access":2
         },
         {
            "access":6
         },
         {
            "access":2
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And I need to convert it into this format:

```
[
   {
      "id":"Site1",
      "access":[1,8]
   },
   {
      "id":"Site2",
      "access":[16]
   },
   {
      "id":"Site3",
      "access":[2,6,2]
   }
]
```

As you can see, I also need to take the keys (site name) and make them the "id" values.

Any ideas on how I can do this in JavaScript (I'm using angular v9)? I'm not very good at restructuring that type of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
2. [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = {
    Site1: {
        week: [
            {
                access: 1,
            },
            {
                access: 8,
            },
        ],
    },
    Site2: {
        week: [
            {
                access: 16,
            },
        ],
    },
    Site3: {
        week: [
            {
                access: 2,
            },
            {
                access: 6,
            },
            {
                access: 2,
            },
        ],
    },
};

const result = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
    id: key,
    access: data[key].week.map(w => w.access),
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help thanks a lot! It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You can first take `entries` and then map it:

```js
var data={ "Site1":{ "week":[ { "access":1 }, { "access":8 } ] }, "Site2":{ "week":[ { "access":16 } ] }, "Site3":{ "week":[ { "access":2 }, { "access":6 }, { "access":2 } ] }};

var result = Object.entries(data).map(([k,v])=>({id:k, access: v.week.map(p=>p.access)}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use this code for your desired result.

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => (
    {
        id: key,
        access: data[key].week.map(obj => obj.access),
    }
))
```

Let me know if you face any issue.